# getQuantityString not working on real device

Tags: android, plural

I got an odd problem. The `getQuantityString()` method working on android studio simulator, but not working on the real device.

This is my code in `strings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <plurals name="subtitle_plural">
        <item quantity="one">%1$s crime</item>
        <item quantity="other">%1$s crimes</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

code in my Fragment:

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
int crimeSize = crimeLab.getCrimes().size();
String subTitle = getResources()
                .getQuantityString(R.plurals.subtitle_plural, crimeSize, crimeSize);
```

When I run the project on the simulator, it works. but if run it on real device, `subTitle` will always be `** crimes` even if `crimeSize` equals `1`.

How did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You should use like that:

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
int crimeSize = crimeLab.getCrimes().size();
String subTitle = String.format(getResources()
                .getQuantityString(R.plurals.subtitle_plural, crimeSize, crimeSize));
```

Comment: No, it's still not working on real device. Is this working on your device?

Comment: Yes, It's worked for me. Maybe crimeSize isn't 1. I tried on SM-G920F.

Comment: It's so wired. Both my HUA WEI and Smartisan were not woking.

Comment: Did you try when crimeSize=1 ?

Comment: of cause i did.  `getQuantityString() ` will not return correct result even let crimeSize equals 1.